# How to debug gunicorn and python in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I am running a python 3.7 application with gunicorn in Google App Engine flex. When the app starts a resource intensive task, the following gets logged in the cloud logs and I can see that the task does not get completed.

> [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 46

In this [thread](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1663) various fixes are proposed. As mentioned in the thread, gunicorn doesn't seem to log the cause for why a worker is being booted. However, it is reported [in a comment](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1663#issuecomment-509238815) that dmesg could be used to debug the cause for the issue.

I am able to get inside the container where my app is running by following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#gcloud). However, when running `dmesg` I get an error:

```
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
```

Any ideas on how to find the cause of gunicorn worker being booted? Might be a memory issue, but it would be good to verify the cause first.

Here are the gunicorn configs being used:

```
workers = 2
threads = 2
timeout = 7200
worker_class = "gthread"
loglevel = "debug"
```

The relevant settings in my app.yaml for Google App Engine:

```
env: flex

manual_scaling:
    instances: 1

resources:
    cpu: 2
    memory_gb: 12
    disk_size_gb: 20
```

Comment: Running out of memory is a possible cause.  There are so many log messages that it easy to miss the important ones. Try taking a closer look at your logs.

Comment: I was not able to debug the problem as I had hoped, but the issue indeed turned out to be a memory issue. I used a [profiler](https://github.com/pythonspeed/filprofiler) to measure the memory footprint when running the python app locally. I then changed the code to run some of the memory intensive processing in s separate process. After these changes, I was able to deploy to Google App Engine without the booting problem.

Comment: I think that you can move your comment to an answer to help others, also you can use  [GCP profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler) to monitor the resources usage on App engine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's latest comment

I was not able to debug the problem as I had hoped, but the issue indeed turned out to be a memory issue. I used a profiler to measure the memory footprint when running the python app locally. I then changed the code to run some of the memory intensive processing in s separate process. After these changes, I was able to deploy to Google App Engine without the booting problem.

Also in similar scenarios it is possible to use [GCP profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler) to monitor the resources usage on App engine.

Comment: Have you used GCP profiler with gunicorn to get info like wait times from the workers? I have failed with that so far and have not found info. Thinking of posting a new question but this one is quite close.